# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2010

I checked above notes but they are not helpful.I am using VS2008 for ASP.Net and MS Access 2010 as a database.
I need to upload the data from excel to database through ASP web page.

But I am receiving an error as below :

"The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'C:\Users\poonamj\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SmartTool\SmartTool\Uploads\'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data."

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace SmartTool
{

    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
            Response.ContentType = ContentType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            Response.End();
        }
        protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
            File.Delete(filePath);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        protected void ViewFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
           // File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            //GridView2.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            //GridView2.DataBind();
            //string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            //GridView2.DataSource = content.
           // OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
           // conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/poonamj/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/SmartTool/SmartTool/fallout.accdb;User id=admin;Password=";
           // conn.Open();

            string Access = Server.MapPath("App_Data/fallout.accdb");
            string Excel = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
            string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Mode=12;";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * INTO [MS Access;Database=" + Access + "].[New Table] FROM [Sheet1$]";
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
                List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = files;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to comment, but cannot.

Did you check the following? Each one enlists possible solutions that can help you.

**Official Microsoft Support page**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306269

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/3479cc5a-2bca-4e9c-9fdb-ec3f96065a52

Additionally, try using the full path including the file name for your Data Source. The following is flawed:

```
 string Excel = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
```

You want to append the Excel file name after `Uploads/`.

Comment: file name is not same all the time. It is dynamic so i cannot specify the file name:(

Comment: Define a string variable that contains the current file name. Keep it up to date and append its value after `Uploads\ `. For example: `Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" & strVariableContainingFileName)`. Does this help?

Comment: hey its worked ...                                                        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;           string Excel = Server.MapPath(Path.GetFileName(filePath));

Comment: but now getting different error message ... Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only. :(

Comment: Check permissions on the Excel file you are using. Right click on the file and open _Properties_. Ensure that it is not marked `Read-Only` under `Attributes`.

Comment: No its not marked Read-Only ...  folder and database files are also unmarked from read only

Comment: Make sure the filePath value is valid: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245407 AND
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304146

Answer (score 0):

I've used a tool like this to troubleshoot the problem in the past: http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/ , more importantly it's view locks on a directory functionality.

I dunno, if I'm overthinking this, but 'C:\Users\poonamj\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SmartTool\SmartTool\Uploads\' is a directory, where it seems to be expecting a file.

An example would be 'C:\Users\poonamj\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SmartTool\SmartTool\Uploads\db.mdb' is a path to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying a file name for Excel and that is causing the exception.

```
string Excel = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/MyFile.xls");
string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Mode=12;";
```

Add a file name to Excel and this problem should be solved.

Comment: file name is not same all the time. It is dynamic so i cannot specify the file name:(